# Passagem de parâmetro no LIMIT do Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

estou a criar um sistema de paginação e no mysql estou a usar desta forma

eu pego do registro 1 e ando ate o 20

```
SELECT * FROM sistema LIMIT 1 , 20
```

eu pego do registro 2 e ando ate o 21

```
SELECT * FROM sistema LIMIT 2 , 21
```

e assim por diante mais eu quero que tenha mais um LIMIT por exemplo se tiver 500 registro que fazer desta maneira

SELECT * FROM sistema LIMIT 300

mais na mesma query quero paginar dentro deste 300 registro algo como

```
SELECT * FROM sistema LIMIT 1 , 20 , 300
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A linguagem SQL não permite. O que ela permite é fazer `UNION ALL`:

```
(SELECT * FROM sistema LIMIT 1, 300)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM sistema LIMIT 20, 300)
ORDER BY alguma_coisa;
```

O `UNION ALL` junta os resultados dos dois `SELECT`s e o `ORDER BY` (opcional) ordena com base em algum critério para ficarem mais consistentes.

Opcionalmente você pode usar somente `UNION` em vez de `UNION ALL`, vai depender do que você deseja fazer. `UNION` mescla os resultados dos `SELECT`s eliminando duplicatas, `UNION ALL` não elimina.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, pelo que entendi você quer 300 registros paginados de 20 em 20 certo?

Se for isso, você pode retornar normalmente os 300 registros com SQL.

```
SELECT * FROM sistema LIMIT 300;
```

E então quebrar em partes de 20 na programação. Em PHP você pode utilizar  a função [array_chunck](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-chunk.php):

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM sistema LIMIT 300;');
$stmt->execute();

$resultados = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$porPagina = 20;
$manterIndice = true;
$paginados = array_chunk($resultados, $porPagina , $manterIndice);

foreach($paginados as $paginado){
    foreach($paginado as $index => $item){

    }
}
```

Outra opção ainda para quebrar em partes na programação seria trabalhar com alguma library de Collections, como a do [Laravel](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html)  por exemplo.

Espero que ajude.